# Bitlocker wants recovery key after system update

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, recovery

I use Windows 10 with my laptop. I made a Windows update which lead into a system update for my laptop.

After that when I start I get prompted for the Bitlocker recovery key. But I do not have one, neither on a stick or in my Microsoft account.

Do I have to reinstall Windows or is there another way to recover my current installation?

Comment: Another common way for saving the Bitlocker recovery key is to print it out. If you don't have the key and the system drive is Bitlocker encrypted that yo have to erase the HDD/SSD and reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer apparently was bitlocked by the vendor.
As you have not saved a recovery key, in effect you have lost the disk.
I can't say what went wrong after Windows was updated, so that now you're
prompted for the key.

I suggest looking in the BIOS for any option that can disable this
check (the chanced are slim of finding anything).

Then I suggest getting in touch with Support of your vendor or
that of the company that made your motherboard.

If the above doesn't help, you'll need to reinstall Windows from
scratch (this time perhaps without Bitlock).